Azure Web App & Static Web App throwing Mixed Content Error
I have a FastAPI server running on Azure Web App with url: https://my-api.azurewebsites.net. I also have a static website running on Azure Static Web App with url: https://myapp.azurestaticapps.net. This web app has GET and POST async apis implemented as follows:
@router.get("/v1/user/{user_id}")
async def get_user(user_id: str):
  # if user exists
  # # return user
  # else
  # # raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

My static web app is making an async GET call to https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/v1/user with the user_id parameter which is supposed to send a response. If the response is 404 then take certain actions. But, before I can check the response, I'm getting the following error on my static web app:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.azurestaticapps.net/dashboard/profile' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://my-api.azurewebsites.net/v1/user/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What should I be looking for in order to resolve this issue?

The problem is likely going to be in your static app. It looks like you are making a request to an http endpoint. Find where you call the API in your app and make sure it starts with https. Or, if you need it to work with both (http locally, perhaps) then skip the scheme entirely and just use //my-api.azurewebsites.net and it will reuse the same scheme (http/https) that your app is using. If this isn't the issue, then we need to see more code.

In case, you have enforced https on the application level/on Azure Portal, please turn it off and then verify (just to isolate the issue).
To do this, from Azure Portal> TLS/SSL settings blade, toggle HTTPS Only to Off and then test, and later enable the HTTPs toggle back on.

@KonceptGeek Azure Static Web App  code  in nextjs?

we need to enable feature to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in Configuration in azure portal in azure web app  .

add this in back end # New endpoint to fetch user by query parameter @app.get("/v1/user") async def get_user_by_query(user_id: str = Query(...)):     if user_id in users:         return users[user_id]     else:         raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

The "Mixed Content" error occurs because your HTTPS page  is trying to make a request to an HTTP URL.
Thanks @mherzig for the comment .
Adding to  his comment  we need to enable feature to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in Configuration in azure portal .


Below is the FastAPI backend and a React frontend to fetch, display user data. The backend code is a FastAPI application providing endpoints to manage user data, including fetching a user by ID, creating a new user, and retrieving all users, with CORS configured.
I followed  this link to use FastAPI  with Python
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Query
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

# Example user data
users = {"1": {"name": "John Doe", "email": "john@example.com"}}

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str

# Configure CORS to allow all origins
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/v1/user/{user_id}")
async def get_user(user_id: str):
    if user_id in users:
        return users[user_id]
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

@app.post("/v1/user/{user_id}")
async def create_user(user_id: str, user: User):
    if user_id in users:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="User already exists")
    users[user_id] = user.dict()
    return users[user_id]

@app.get("/v1/users")
async def get_all_users():
    return users

# New endpoint to fetch user by query parameter
@app.get("/v1/user")
async def get_user_by_query(user_id: str = Query(...)):
    if user_id in users:
        return users[user_id]
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

# Run the app using uvicorn
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

azure web app output:


The frontend nextjs code is a React component that uses the useEffect hook to fetch user data from the backend based on a query parameter, handles loading and error states, displays the user’s profile information.
I followed  this Doc for nextjs code.
'use client';

import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

const UserPage = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const userId = searchParams.get('user_id');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      if (!userId) {
        setError('User ID is required');
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      try {
        
        const response = await fetch(`https://Azureweb Appname.azurewebsites.net/v1/user?user_id=${userId}`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setUserData(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, [userId]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Profile</h1>
      {userData ? (
        <div>
          <p>Name: {userData.name}</p>
          <p>Email: {userData.email}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No user data available</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const SuspendedUserPage = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
    <UserPage />
  </Suspense>
);

export default SuspendedUserPage;

yml:
 app_location: "/" 
 api_location: "" 
 output_location: "" 
   

package.json:
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":">=18.0.0"
  },

Deployement status:

Azure Satatic web app:

